# Displaying an array with foreach in a variable PHP

Tags: php, arrays, email, foreach

I've only skimmed through, but I wanted to get my first question out here, seeing as I haven't found a specific and similar example/inquiry.

I have on the 'first page' of a site many groups of varying companies. In each group are 1 - 20 or so check-boxed input fields so that a client can require different information be sent to them after they submit the form below. On a separate page that only runs a php script, I email the form to the host company. The message then displays as so: (and I changed content...)

I want it to read:

```
            *Favorite Animals: Dog, Cat, Bird*
```

However I have it reading:

```
            Favorite Animals: Dog,
            Favorite Animals: Cat,
            Favorite Animals: Bird,
```

**My Code:**

On the first page we have a list of different checkboxes in the same array with obvious different values... like shown below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="animals[]" value="Dogs" class="cb">
 Dogs<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="animals[]" value="Cats" class="cb">
 Cats<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="animals[]" value="Birds" class="cb">
 Birds<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="animals[]" value="Dragons" class="cb">
 Dragons<br>
```

The above code is then submitted (via post) to a separate php document.

The relevant code in this second page is:

```
$animals = $_POST['animals'];
```

below...

```
    foreach ($animals as $an) {
$email_message .= "Favorite Animals: ".clean_string($an)." ,\n";
    }
```

I realize what's going on, but I haven't figured out a way to work the foreach statement so that the "Favorite Animal's" is displayed once, followed by the possible array of whatever was selected on the previous page.

I have no errors, only getting the information in a way I don't desire. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the static parts outside the loop. That should do it.

```
 $email_message .= "Favorite Animals: ";

 foreach ($animals as $an) {
   $email_message .= clean_string($an)." ,";
 }
  $email_message = rtrim ($email_message, ",");

 $email_message .= "\n";

 // Continue appending rest of the email message
```

Comment: @Yaroslav, Done. Thought its self explanatory since he is almost there. Didn't know it would be felt rude.

Comment: Yea, this is what I finished with. Can't believe I didn't think of that. It's not the biggest problem, but the only thing is that after each array variable has been passed, it will undoubtedly insert a single last " ,". I feel it would take a math work around of some sort I'd have to hash out for a little... or? is there an easier way...

Comment: haha. no it was understood. I understand what's going on perfectly, I just didn't think it out all the way. Thanks again.

Comment: Use substr() or rtrim() to remove the last comma outside of the loop?

Comment: Edited my answer to add rtrim.

Comment: not that you need to, but don't forget the end semicolon after the rtrim ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `foreach` and dealing with the extra comma yourself, use `implode`.

```
$email_message = implode(', ', array_map('clean_string', $animals);
```

Comment: thank you @Barmar , I've been trying to understand the implode function. I'll see to it.

Comment: will this also work if I'm working with multiple array variables... i.e., $toys, $hats...? thank you

Comment: also, my clean_string is a function like so:                  `function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }`

Comment: With multiple variables, you'll want to call it multiple times: `$animal_msg = implode(..., $animals); $toy_msg = implode(..., $toys); etc.`. It doesn't matter what your clean_string function is.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the string `$email_message` with **"Favorite Animals: "** and then **just append** the rest of the array in loop

```
$email_message = "Favorite Animals: ";
 foreach ($animals as $an) {
$email_message .= clean_string($an)." , ";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was over-thinking it. I don't have too much experience with the foreach.

Comment: @GBD It will. and if not can you tell me why?

Comment: But it did print it out once.

Comment: haha sorry, meant to say, that yes, I already had the finished product, with Animals only printed out once. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that the form is only posting what was selected, and not what wasn't selected. What you probably want is for it to display a list of all possible values of animals along with their selection. To do this I would change your submit form and let it post with all values:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="animals['Dogs']" onclick="this.value='yes'" value="no" class="cb">
 Dogs<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="animals['Cats']" onclick="this.value='yes'" value="no" class="cb">
 Cats<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="animals['Birds']" onclick="this.value='yes'" value="no" class="cb">
 Birds<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="animals['Dragons']" onclick="this.value='yes'" value="no" class="cb">
 Dragons<br>
```

And your email print function should be updated to include the keys in the array now:

```
$email_message = "Favorite Animals:";
foreach ($animals as $key=>$val) {
  $email_message .=".clean_string($key). "=" . clean_string($val) . " ,\n";
}
```

So what is happening is that all values are being passed, but they're changing from 'no' to 'yes' when someone clicks on them. This is a workaround, there are other ways of handling it, but they may require updating more than just your form.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are much better, but just some food for thought you could also achieve this with conditional statements like this:

```
$animals = array('Animal 1', 'Animal 2', 'Animal 3');
$email_message = "";
$firstTime = true;
foreach ($animals as $an) {
    if ($firstTime === true) {
        $email_message .= "Favorite Animals: ".$an." ,\n";
        $firstTime = false;
    } else {
        $email_message .= $an." ,\n";
    }
}

$email_message = substr($email_message, 0, -3);
echo $email_message;
```